# Can Combine be used in struct (instead of class)?

Tags: swift, combine

When using [Combine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine) as below

```
var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

func loadItems(tuple : (name : String, imageURL : URL)) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: tuple.imageURL)
        .sink(
            receiveCompletion: {
                completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure( _):
                    return
                }},
            receiveValue: { data, _ in DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in self?.displayFlag(data: data, title: tuple.name) } })
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

We don't need to call `cancel` in the `deinit` as below

```
deinit {
    cancellables.forEach {
        $0.cancel()
    }
}
```

Given that in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable, it is stated:

> **An AnyCancellable instance automatically calls cancel() when deinitialized.**

Given we don't need to release during deinit, can the Combine be used in `struct` instead of `class`?

Comment: there's no inherent problem using Combine (i'm assuming you mean, subscribing to a Combine publisher) inside `struct`. It would de-init and all. But you'd run into issues if you tried to use `self` inside `.sink`

Comment: If you're going to modify self like in receiveValue above, then no, you can't use combine in that way with structs. But if you are going just hold publisher in scruct but modify something outside that there is no problem with releasing, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I assume the `AnyCancellation` will still automatically get released even in struct, there's no `deinit`, right?

Comment: I don't understand your question, regardless of struct of class, once the owners of `AnyCancellable` disappear, so will the cancellables. It makes no difference the reference is hold by a class or a struct (or even a closure).

Comment: Thanks @Cristik. I'm just wondering what mechanism did `AnyCancellable` use to determine it can be freed. If it is using the `class` `deinit`, then it won't work in `struct`. If it is using other mechanism that also works for class and struct, then yes, they should work for both.

Comment: [AnyCancellable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable) is a class, thus is has a deinitializer.

Answer (score 9):

To answer your question directly, `AnyCancellable` does not rely on being stored in a class in order to cancel itself. Like any ref-counted object, it can be stored in a struct just fine, and it will be properly de-initialized and thus cancelled when there are no more references to it.

That said, you are correct to be suspicious here. You probably *don't* want to store an `AnyCancellable` in a struct the way you are doing it here. For starters, you would have to mark your `loadItems` function as `mutating` to even get it to compile, because storing the `AnyCancellable` means mutating the `cancellables` array.

Typically, if you're storing an `AnyCancellable` then you are associating that operation with something that has true identity, and thus is better represented as a class. You are basically saying "cancel this operation when this instance goes away". For example, if you're downloading an image to display in a `UIViewController`, you probably want to cancel that download if the `UIViewController` goes away because the user dismissed it; that is to say, the download operation is associated with a *particular instance* of `UIViewController`.

Since structs have value semantics, it is almost conceptually incoherent to have an `AnyCancellable` associated with an "instance" of a struct. Structs don't have instances, they just have values. When you pass a struct as an argument to a function, it creates a copy. That means if the function called `loadItems` then only the function's own copy of the struct value would store the `AnyCancellable`, and the operation would be immediately cancelled when the function returns because your original copy of the value is not storing the `AnyCancellable`.

Comment: Thanks for the overview and suggestions. I still wonder, however, what about storing the `AnyCancellable?` value into a static variable of a `struct`?. Even if the  subscription is recreated, the cancellable reference will be store and shared among all values. This is indented for example to trigger some analytics events from the struct value, via other static methods. But would that e.g., lead to strong reference cycles? Or?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `deinit` and don't need to call

```
cancellables.forEach {
    $0.cancel()
}
```

I agree it's quite confusing that `AnyCancellable` have method `cancel`, that actually you don't need to call.
Publishers are automatically cancelled, when cancellables got disposed.
That is why you receive nothing if forget to store them somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I think `cancel()` is still there in the event if one wanted to terminate the process before it has ended. My question is more towards does `cancellable` uses the internal `deinit` of class to determine if it will be terminated? If yes, then would this. a problem if we use it in `struct`, given `struct` doesn't have `deinit`?